# Host Custom Domain with VPN?

Tags: vpn, dns, bind, tld

is it possible to host a custom TLD on a VPN? And if so, does that mean that to resolve the custom domain you just have to be connected to the VPN?

Thanks again,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Many websites are only accessible while connected to a specific network, or from specific locations.

I would host your DNS records publicly, though.

Comment: How would I host DNS records in a VPN?

Comment: Never tried that, but it's easy to set up a service like DNS and then block the world from accessing port 53 unless they are connected via vpn, or whitelisted through your firewall.

Comment: I'm not trying to block people from using my DNS server. But is it possible to resolve custom DNS records using a VPN?